# Maven could not resolve dependencies for project

Tags: maven, maven-3, serenity-bdd

From this page https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-demos i downloaded the file which I imported to eclipse. I tried to run tests from the "jbehave-webtests" project. During running these tests I'm getting following error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Sample Serenity JBehave project 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:jar:1.1.22-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for net.serenity-bdd:serenity-rest-assured:jar:1.1.22-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for net.serenity-bdd:serenity-jbehave:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.690 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-03-21T10:33:24+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/153M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project serenity-jbehave-showcase: Could not resolve dependencies for project net.serenitybdd.showcase:serenity-jbehave-showcase:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:jar:1.1.22-SNAPSHOT, net.serenity-bdd:serenity-rest-assured:jar:1.1.22-SNAPSHOT, net.serenity-bdd:serenity-jbehave:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:jar:1.1.22-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

I run the test with this goal: clean verify
I think that base directory is correctly set "${workspace_loc:/serenity-demos/jbehave-webtests}"

How can I resolve this problem? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: as mentionned  : you got 3 dependencies missing : `net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:jar:1.1.22-SNAPSHOT, net.serenity-bdd:serenity-rest-assured:jar:1.1.22-SNAPSHOT, net.serenity-bdd:serenity-jbehave:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:jar:1.1.22-SNAPSHOT` try to dl them form maven repository or if you don't find them : download them and install them manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see on the maven repository: [serenity-bdd](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-core),

There is no version 1.1.22 available. Only rc versions are available for download. Either you can change the dependency to use one of those 1.1.22-rc.x jars or you can upgrade to 1.1.24 and above series.

Comment: Where should I make changes in my pom.xml? I have no experience with maven.

Comment: In the dependency  `net.serenity-bdd`
In the `<version>` you change the number of the version with 1.1.22-rc.x

Comment: Maven has downloaded some jar files. Now I have a new error: Failed to execute goal net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins:serenity-maven-plugin:1.1.21:aggregate (serenity-reports) on project serenity-jbehave-showcase: Execution serenity-reports of goal net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins:serenity-maven-plugin:1.1.21:aggregate failed: Plugin net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins:serenity-maven-plugin:1.1.21 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:jar:1.1.22-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]

Comment: You have to update the <dependencies> section in your pom file. Look into that section, find all <dependency> with serenity-bdd, and update them all to correct versions using the maven repository link specified above. Or else you can post a code snippet from the you pom file here.

Answer (score 2):

When you get such error it means jar is not downloaded from MVN repo due to some reason,
Reason can be wrong version or no connection etc.

Try to find proper version in MVN repo in link  shared below, and also try to check in .m2 folder if jar is downloaded

Some time is maven fails to download a jar file if .lastupdated extension is created. Make sure you delete that file before update.

Never build your project without resolving all dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
    <artifactId>serenity-rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.21</version>
</dependency>
```

Add this in your POM,

Inside `<dependencies>`

Or find required version from list [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-rest-assured)